# Do Shintani zeta functions satisfy a functional equation?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, reference-request

Probably my questions are known or evident to the experts but I'm a bit puzzled. First of all there seem to be two kinds of zeta functions that go under the name of Shintani zeta functions.

First, there are zeta functions $\zeta^{SS}$ associated with so called prehomogenous vector spaces going back to important work by Sato and Shintani (see the original [article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdfplus/1970844.pdf?acceptTC=true) or this [book](http://books.google.de/books/about/Shintani_zeta_functions.html?id=Cf4TYjn5Hp0C&redir_esc=y) by Yukie) and then, second, zeta functions $\zeta^S$ that appeared in Shintani's work on special values of Dedekind zeta functions of totally real number fields at negative integers (see Shintani's [article](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1978.2/Main/icm1978.2.0591.0598.ocr.pdf) or Neukirch's [book](http://books.google.de/books/about/Algebraic_number_theory.html?id=plE3PwAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) for example).

1) I'm mainly interested in the question if it is known (or expected) if the latter zeta functions $\zeta^S$ satisfy functional equations. (From what I understand the $\zeta^{SS}$ satisfy functional equations or are expected to satisfy in case it is not proven).

Let me just note that one can write Shintani zeta functions in the following form $$\Gamma(s)^n \zeta^S(s,z,x) = \int_0^\infty \cdots\int_0^\infty \sum_{z_1,\dots , z_n=0}^\infty e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n t_i L_i(z+x)}(t_1\cdots t_n)^{s-1} dt_1\cdots dt_n$$
where the $L_i(x)$ are linear forms, i.e. essentially we could say that we're looking at multivariable theta-like functions and Mellin transforms thereof. So the question can be rephrased in asking whether these theta-like functions occurring in the above integral satisfy a functional equation/theta inversion formula. (Note that these theta-like functions do in general not come from symplectic structures, i.e. they are not related to abelian varieties (at least as far as I see)).

2) But next to this question I'm also extremely interested in the relationship of these two kinds of zeta functions. In which cases do the two constructions agree? Is there anything known?

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT: OK, so I could speak a bit with one of the absolute authorities in this field and I learned, that

1) 
one shouldn't expect functional equations for single functions $\zeta^S$ but rather for certain finite linear combinations and

2) 
one shouldn't expect relations between the two notions of "zeta" functions.

This doesn't destroy the applications I had in mind with my question but I have to rethink the question and will try to give a better and less naive version of it soon. Thank you so far very much for your helpful comments!

Comment: The integral equals $\prod_{i=1}^n L_i(x)^{-s}$, at least when $\Re L_i(x)>0$ for all $i$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Dear GH, yes, exactly. 

Comment: Bora, thanks. But then I don't see why it is called a zeta function: it has no arithmetic in it. I am not saying it is not useful for arithmetic, I just don't know why would it satisfy any functional equation.

Comment: Dear GH, I agree, the formulation of $\zeta^S$ is very general (also a bit sloppy) and independent from a number theoretical context. So, maybe it's rather a question about these theta-like functions. When I'm not mistaken, then for example theta functions for abelian varieties à la Mumford are special cases and they satisfy of course a functional equation, or the Riemann zeta as a "trivial" special case. Maybe I should edit the question and explain exactly the kind of Shintani zeta function that occurs in the number theoretic context I'm interested in...

Comment: Regarding "there seem to be two kinds of zeta functions that go under the name of Shintani zeta functions": I can definitively confirm this. I know about the prehomogeneous ones, but unfortunately not about the ones you asked about. AFAIK the only connection is that Shintani worked on both of them. But if there is some further connection I would be very interested to hear about it!

Comment: @Bora: My problem is that the expression $\prod_{i=1}^n L_i(x)^{-s}$ is not theta-like. To me a theta-like function is an infinite series such as $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-n^2 x}$ whose Mellin-transform is a zeta-like function.

Comment: @Bora and GH : probably one needs to take an infinite sum (over $x$) of the expression Bora has written. One can also introduce denominators in the integrand.

Comment: @GH, I'm sorry, only now I realize, that I was too sloppy, you're completely right! I simply forgot to write the sum....

Comment: @François: Yes, exactly, thank you very much!

Comment: In case it is not clear: the integral kernel is akin to one used by Riemann in one of his proofs for plain-old-zeta. _Not_ the theta series, but $\sum e^{-nx} = 1/(e^x-1)$. The "cone" here is just the positive reals. For other number fields, the cone is a product of positive reals, but the rational structure is more complicated.

So, in principle, it _is_ related to the bigger-group Shintani zetas. I think Shintani did a few things about their special values, and I recall Satake wrote a paper about this.

Comment: @Bora: looks much better. 

Comment: Dear Paul, thank you very much for your comment. I will try to have a look at the literature you indicate. I'm aware of the fact that for Shintani zetas $\zeta^S$ one looks at generalizations of $1 / (e^x-1)$ which give rise to generalized Bernoulli numbers and in this way to special values at negative integers of $\zeta^S$. My question is rather if there is a theta function behind. For the Riemann zeta "everything" (special values at negative integers, quadratic reciprocity) can be done from the point of view of the (Jacobi) theta function (viewed as a heat kernel). 

Comment: I don't know if this will answer your question but Colmez gave a talk recently in Banff about Shintani's method. The notes (by Matt Greenberg) are available here : http://temple.birs.ca/~11w5125/colmez.pdf What I remember is that Colmez managed to express special values at negative integers without using the functional equation.

Comment: Dear François, thank you very much for your link. The method described by Colmez is exactly Shintani's approach, i.e. the zeta function $\zeta^S$ is expressed in terms of a contour integral and this allows to circumvent the use of a functional equation. My question is if there could nevertheless be a functional equation behind? (In some cases there is, but even if in general there is no functional equation, I'd like to understand the obstruction).

Comment: @Bora : not being an expert, I don't really know (but this "without using the functional equation" could imply that there is indeed one...)

Answer (score 2):

there was a talk recently in RIMS Kyota titled something like
"the functional equation of the Shintani zeta function".
You might try looking that up.

Comment: Searching gives me this: http://math.stanford.edu/~fthorne/shintani-proceedings-final.pdf. Who was the talk by that you are thinking of?

Comment: @David: The Shintani zeta functions that Frank Thorne studies are the first type $\zeta^{SS}$ that OP mentions.

Comment: This paper by Hirose-Sato might be the one related to $\zeta^S$ that the RIMS talk was discussing : https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.7716.
The $\zeta^S$ indeed satisfy some functional equation.